# is reference assignment atomic in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, thread-safety, ios-multithreading

Do I need some kind of explicit synchronization in this case?

```swift
class A { 
  let val: Int; 
  init(_ newVal: Int) { 
    val = newVal
   }
}

public class B {
  var a: A? = nil
  public func setA() { a = A(0) }
  public func hasA() -> Bool { return a != nil }
}
```

There is also another method in class **B**:

```swift
public func resetA() {
  guard hasA() else { return }
  a = A(1)
}
```

`setA()` and `resetA()` may be called from any thread, in any order.

I understand that there may be a race condition, that if concurrently one thread calls `setA()` and another thread calls `resetA()`, the result is not determined: `val` will either be `0`, or `1`, but I don't care: at any rate, `hasA()` will return true, won't it?

Does the answer change if **A** is a **struct** instead of **class**?

Comment: Actually with the given code  – by the way `a` must be optional – you can replace the entire code in `B` with `lazy var a = A()`, this creates the instance (once) lazily,

Comment: @vadian I believe I cannot use `lazy` here: I want to know if `setA()` was explicitly called.

Comment: @vadian `lazy` is not thread-safe / not atomic either.

Comment: `var a: A = nil` this will give you compilation error, what u meant probably is `var a: A? = nil` also I agree with Vadian that using lazy will ensure that there exists only one instance of A there by atomicity of it

Comment: If you want `a` to be thread-safe / atomic, yes, you need to do some additional work. Simplest one is have a `DispatchSemaphore` control access to that var (I saw in public apple's own code they use it a lot for "simple" cases), but if you want something more sophisticated, best to do reader/writer lock, e.g. https://dmytro-anokhin.medium.com/concurrency-in-swift-reader-writer-lock-4f255ae73422

Comment: @Rob, the whole point is that may object is not mutable. Well, see the updated question, which makes it a bit more juicy. Do I need locks, dispatch queues, semaphores, or some other concurrency helpers? I understand that there may be a race condition, that if concurrently one thread calls `setA()` and another thread calls `resetA(1)`, the result is not determined: `val` will either be **0**, or **1**, but I don't care: at any rate, `hasA()` will return `true`, won't it?

Comment: First, you've only just changed your question to make `A` immutable, so it's not sporting to retroactively declare that that was “the whole point”. But let's set that aside. Second, in `B`, you're still exposing property `a`, so that's definitely not thread safe. Third, assuming you fix that, too, the bottom line is that **no**, properties are not atomic. You must synchronize it to make it thread safe. This has been asked and answered many times. See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bswift%5D+atomic+properties

Comment: “Does the answer change if A is a struct instead of class?” ... Nope. Still not atomic. Now, if (1) both `A` and `B` were structs and (2) you ensured that each thread got its own copy, employing value semantics everywhere, then, yes, that does solve the problem.

Comment: @Rob, I have posted an *answer* that uses a lock for all operations. Is it correct in your eyes? Or it is not enough, or too much, or the choice of synchronization mechanism (`os_unfair_lock_lock`) is non-optimal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, no, property accessors are not atomic. See WWDC 2016 video [Concurrent Programming With GCD in Swift 3](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/720/?time=997), which talks about the absence of atomic/synchronization native in the language. (This is a GCD talk, so when they subsequently dive into synchronization methods, they focus on GCD methods, but any synchronization method is fine.) Apple uses a variety of different synchronization methods in their own code. E.g. in [`ThreadSafeArrayStore`](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/b2342f18309258fd7ad1e97ba77765489ec947e4/Sources/Basics/ConcurrencyHelpers.swift#L70) they use [they use `NSLock`](https://github.com/apple/swift-tools-support-core/blob/3d2c6e9c6a63739eb783b8f1891bcabcd2d311b1/Sources/TSCBasic/Lock.swift)).

---

If synchronizing with locks, I might suggest an extension like the following:

```swift
extension NSLocking {
    func synchronized<T>(block: () throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        lock()
        defer { unlock() }
        return try block()
    }
}
```

Apple uses this pattern in their own code, though they happen to call it [`withLock`](https://github.com/apple/swift-tools-support-core/blob/3d2c6e9c6a63739eb783b8f1891bcabcd2d311b1/Sources/TSCBasic/Lock.swift#L31) rather than `synchronized`. But the pattern is the same.

Then you can do:

```swift
public class B {
    private var lock = NSLock()
    private var a: A?             // make this private to prevent unsynchronized direct access to this property

    public func setA() {
        lock.synchronized {
            a = A(0)
        }
    }

    public func hasA() -> Bool {
        lock.synchronized {
            a != nil
        }
    }

    public func resetA() {
        lock.synchronized {
            guard a != nil else { return }
            a = A(1)
        }
    }
}
```

Or perhaps

```swift
public class B {
    private var lock = NSLock()
    private var _a: A?

    public var a: A? {
        get { lock.synchronized { _a } }
        set { lock.synchronized { _a = newValue } }
    }

    public var hasA: Bool {
        lock.synchronized { _a != nil }
    }

    public func resetA() {
        lock.synchronized {
            guard _a != nil else { return }
            _a = A(1)
        }
    }
}
```

---

I confess to some uneasiness in exposing `hasA`, because it practically invites the application developer to write like:

```swift
if !b.hasA {
    b.a = ...
}
```

That is fine in terms of preventing simultaneous access to memory, but it introduced a logical race if two threads are doing it at the same time, where both happen to pass the `!hasA` test, and they both replace the value, the last one wins.

Instead, I might write a method to do this for us:

```
public class B {
    private var lock = NSLock() // replacing os_unfair_lock_s()
    private var _a: A? = nil // fixed, thanks to Rob

    var a: A? {
        get { lock.synchronized { _a } }
        set { lock.synchronized { _a = newValue } }
    }

    public func withA(block: (inout A?) throws -> T) rethrows -> T {
        try lock.synchronized {
            try block(&_a)
        }
    }
}
```

That way you can do:

```swift
b.withA { a in
    if a == nil {
        a = ...
    }
}
```

That is thread safe, because we are letting the caller wrap all the logical tasks (checking to see if `a` is `nil` and, if so, the initialization of `a`) all in one single synchronized step. It is a nice generalized solution to the problem. And it prevents logic races.

---

Now the above example is so abstract that it is hard to follow. So let's consider a practical example, a variation on Apple’s [`ThreadSafeArrayStore`](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/b2342f18309258fd7ad1e97ba77765489ec947e4/Sources/Basics/ConcurrencyHelpers.swift#L70):

```swift
public class ThreadSafeArrayStore<Value> {
    private var underlying: [Value]
    private let lock = NSLock()

    public init(_ seed: [Value] = []) {
        underlying = seed
    }

    public subscript(index: Int) -> Value {
        get { lock.synchronized { underlying[index] } }
        set { lock.synchronized { underlying[index] = newValue } }
    }

    public func get() -> [Value] {
        lock.synchronized {
            underlying
        }
    }

    public func clear() {
        lock.synchronized {
            underlying = []
        }
    }

    public func append(_ item: Value) {
        lock.synchronized {
            underlying.append(item)
        }
    }

    public var count: Int {
        lock.synchronized {
            underlying.count
        }
    }

    public var isEmpty: Bool {
        lock.synchronized {
            underlying.isEmpty
        }
    }

    public func map<NewValue>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> NewValue) rethrows -> [NewValue] {
        try lock.synchronized {
            try underlying.map(transform)
        }
    }

    public func compactMap<NewValue>(_ transform: (Value) throws -> NewValue?) rethrows -> [NewValue] {
        try lock.synchronized {
            try underlying.compactMap(transform)
        }
    }
}
```

Here we have a synchronized array, where we define an interface to interact with the underlying array in a thread-safe manner.

---

Or, if you want an even more trivial example, consider an thread-safe object to keep track of what the tallest item was. We would not have a `hasValue` boolean, but rather we would incorporate that right into our synchronized `updateIfTaller` method:

```swift
public class Tallest {
    private var _height: Float?
    private let lock = NSLock()

    var height: Float? {
        lock.synchronized { _height }
    }

    func updateIfTaller(_ candidate: Float) {
        lock.synchronized {
            guard let tallest = _height else {
                _height = candidate
                return
            }

            if candidate > tallest {
                _height = candidate
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Just a few examples. Hopefully it illustrates the idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot! These examples will definitely help in broader context. My usecase is different.

Comment: OK, now I bang my head on another atomicity issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66224497/how-do-i-capture-a-property-in-thread-safe-way